# How to update id of an object through Postman

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman, put

I have some dummy data in my database where an "activity" instance only contains an activityId as its attribute. Id's are strings and are manually set for now. This is just a test/dummy project.

I call a @RestController in my spring boot project that has a putmapping which should save the changed object.

I want to update an existing activity and just change its id to see if it works.
The putmapping is as follows:

```
@PutMapping("/activity/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Activity> updateActivity(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Activity activity) {
        Optional<Activity> activityOptional = activityRepo.findById(id);
        if (activityOptional.isPresent()) {
            activityRepo.save(activity);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(activity, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

In postman I have made a put request where I call the url: localhost:8080/activity/0001

as I want to update the activity with id=0001. I want to update it to be, say, 0033.

In postman I input the raw json format of what I want it to change to:

```
{
    "activityId": "0033"
}
```

By doing this, it doesn't update the activity but makes a new one with the new id.

How to I actually update the id of an activity?

Answer (score 1):

JPA needs to determine if `save` is new or update. To do so, it will, by default, use the primary key that looks to be your ID. This means that changing your ID will tell JPA that it is a new entry.

Easiest way is probably to use native query. In your repo, have a method something like:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "update activity set activityID = ?1 where activityId = ?2")
void updateActivityId(String newId, String oldId);
```